# Saving matplotlib map to shapefile in python?

Tags: arcpy, python, shapefile, matplotlib

I already plot a prediction map I made with xgboost modal by matplotlib function and I want to save this map as a shapefile so I can work with it in ArcGIS, how can I do that?

Picture of the map:

[image: h]

Comment: Can you say what is the format of this map? It is a raster file? A vector file? I dont' know matplotlib but maybe I can help you to generate a shapefile from the output.

Comment: If the matplotlib map is a load of line plots, it might be possible to write them to a line type shapefile containing multiple layers